# CollectionViewController won't show my text

Tags: swift4, uicollectionviewcell, xcode9

I have a problem with the CollectionViewController. I'm just try to put text in cells without an extra class: 
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZESU.png)
But the text won't show: [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYaiK.png)
Or is it better to do it in a class?

Comment: I don’t know what you mean without a separate class. AFAIK you need to subclass the collection view cell and set up a delegate. Can you share your code?

Comment: didn't make one yet. I just wanna to ask if it should work without class?

Comment: I’m not an expert but the only way I know of is to set up a delegate and a subclass of UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: mhm then I have to make a class, hoped I don't have to do it. but thanks

Comment: No problem - there might be other ways but I don’t know them!